# Add column (lookup field) to another site

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column

I create a column "LookUpValues" of type LookUp in `Site A` but I'm trying to *add from existing site columns* in `Site B` but it doesn´t show up. Is it possible to do it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**.

It is possible to use the content type from one site to another site using **Content type hub**.

But to use the content type from one site to another site, you need to do some configurations. Follow the steps given in below articles to achieve this:

1. [An Introduction To Content Type Hub In SharePoint Office 365](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/An-Introduction-To-Content-Type-Hub-In-SharePoint-Office-365)
2. [Content Type Hub In SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/content-type-hub-in-sharepoint-online/).
3. [Publish a content type from a content publishing hub](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/publish-a-content-type-from-a-content-publishing-hub-58081155-118d-4e7a-9cc5-d43b5dbb7d02).

Comment: I tried but is not working, do you have another option?

Answer (score 0):

If the Site A and Site B are in the same site collection, you can create a site column with lookup type in the root site of the site collection. The site columns are available to all sites in the site collection.

Learn more about [how to create a cross-site lookup site column](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/12/how-to-create-cross-site-lookup-site-column-in-sharepoint.html)

If the Site A and Site B are in the different site collection, you need code to achieve that.

For example, you can do a cross site collection lookup and populate it as a dropdown control in your SharePoint application using jQuery.

The demo:

http://www.sharepointfix.com/2010/11/cross-site-collection-dropdown-look-up.html

Comment: Only works when I create in the root site of the site collection, but in the root site I don't have the list that I want. Do you have another option?

Comment: You also need to create the list in the root site of the site collection.

Comment: I have like 2000 items in the list, I need to copy them.

Comment: You can save this list as the list template and then import it to the top site of the site collection. Or, you can export the list to Excel spreadsheet and then import to list

Comment: I can not save the default list Pages from Sharepoint.

Comment: How to save the list as template: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393